# Python: Problems with final result of password strength program

Tags: python

Lately, I was presented with a challenge exercise, aiming to create a program which checks the length of a password and then assesses it strength based on it being mixed case and containing numbers.

The part which determines whether the length of the password is suitable works absolutely fine, however the rest of the program seems to not work. I am unsure whether this is a logical or syntax error of some sort. I hope you can help me in some way.

```
import re
#score variable, responsible for later defining if passwords is weak, medium or strong
Score = 0
Password = ""
#inputs password
Password = input("Please enter a password:")
Password_length = len(Password)
#checks password length (6-12), asks user to re-input until password is within boundaries
while Password_length < 6 or Password_length > 12:
    if Password_length < 6:
        Outputted_length = "too short"
        Outputted_criteria = "no shorter than 6 characters"
    else:
        Outputted_length = "too long"
        Outputted_criteria = "no longer than 12 characters"
    print("Your password is", Outputted_length, ". It has to be", Outputted_criteria, ".")
    Password = input("Please enter a password:")
    Password_length = len(Password)
else:
    #defines function for checking for presence of numbers in password
    def hasNumbers(s):
        return any(i.isdigit() for i in s)
    #checks if password is all upper case
    Is_upper = Password.isupper()
    if Is_upper == "True":
        Score = Score - 1
    else:
        Score = Score + 1
    #checks if passwords is all lower case
    Is_lower = Password.islower()
    if Is_lower == "False":
        Score = Score - 1
    else:
        Score = Score + 1
    #checks if password contains a number
    Number_presence = hasNumbers(Password)
    if Number_presence == "True":
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        Score = Score - 1
    #checks if password is just numbers
    Only_numbers = Password.isdigit()
    if Only_numbers == "True":
        Score = Score - 1
    #outputs weak, medium or strong to user based on score value
    if Score <= 0:
        print("Your password is absolutely rubbish!")
    if Score == 1:
        print("Your password is weak, you should try again.")
    elif Score == 2:
        print("Your password is medium, it should be OK.")
    elif Score == 3:
        print("Your password is strong, it is absolutely fine.")
    else:
        print("The program has experienced a problem. Please try again!")
        exit()
```

Comment: `if Is_lower == "False":` nope. Booleans are not strings. replace by `if not Is_lower`

Comment: *"seems to not work"* is a profoundly unhelpful description of the problem. Give a [mcve].

Comment: "I am unsure whether this is a logical or syntax error of some sort": you should know: you're the first one to try to run this code.

Comment: respect for coding at 13 you have your whole coder life ahead of you. Start on the right foot and read this awesome page:http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Comment: If you remove `== "True"` and `== "False"` from all of the if statements, the program will work correctly. (Even better, use `if Password.isupper():`, `if Password.islower():`, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has some pre-defined statements that are part of it. One of these is Boolean : `True` and `False`

When you call the built in isupper() function in python, it doesn't return a string, it returns a Boolean, and so does most other similar functions.

True and "True" are very different things. `True` is a Boolean type value, while "True" is just a string. This is a common mistake all new python programmers make, due to the fact that in python, you don't have to specify different value types like you do in c++ or Java. It is still important to know about data types as to avoid such fatal errors and to further advance your knowledge in Python :)

To read more about Data Types: http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-datatypes/

I have looked at your code and fixed some mistakes ( not tested ):

```
import re
#score variable, responsible for later defining if passwords is weak, medium or strong
Score = 0
Password = ""
#inputs password
Password = input("Please enter a password:")
Password_length = len(Password)
#checks password length (6-12), asks user to re-input until password is within boundaries
while Password_length < 6 or Password_length > 12:
    if Password_length < 6:
        Outputted_length = "too short"
        Outputted_criteria = "no shorter than 6 characters"
    else:
        Outputted_length = "too long"
        Outputted_criteria = "no longer than 12 characters"
    print("Your password is", Outputted_length, ". It has to be", Outputted_criteria, ".")
    Password = input("Please enter a password:")
    Password_length = len(Password)
else:
    #defines function for checking for presence of numbers in password
    def hasNumbers(s):
        return any(i.isdigit() for i in s)
    #checks if password is all upper case
    Is_upper = Password.isupper()
    if Is_upper == True:
        Score = Score - 1
    else:
        Score = Score + 1
    #checks if passwords is all lower case
    Is_lower = Password.islower()
    if Is_lower == False:
        Score = Score - 1
    else:
        Score = Score + 1
    #checks if password contains a number
    Number_presence = hasNumbers(Password)
    if Number_presence == True:
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        Score = Score - 1
    #checks if password is just numbers
    Only_numbers = Password.isdigit()
    if Only_numbers == True:
        Score = Score - 1
    #outputs weak, medium or strong to user based on score value
    if Score <= 0:
        print("Your password is absolutely rubbish!")
    if Score == 1:
        print("Your password is weak, you should try again.")
    elif Score == 2:
        print("Your password is medium, it should be OK.")
    elif Score == 3:
        print("Your password is strong, it is absolutely fine.")
    else:
        print("The program has experienced a problem. Please try again!")
        exit()
```

*As a sidenote, you can make your program less verbose by just completley removing the `== True` and `== False` from your code. By default, if and while statements will check if a value is True or False, and run the code indented under them if it is True

Comment: The logic of the `islower` test is wrong. The password is strongest when it contains a mixture of upper, lower, and digits. That is: the bigger the pool of possible characters, the harder the password is to crack. Ideally, there should be a check for punctuation, as well.